# use pingdom to monitor soap service

Tags: soap, pingdom

I'm sending a SOAP request to my server via Pingdom -- just put the XML content in the POST data field. 
When clicking "Test Check", the button greys out for a few seconds and then comes back.
I've tried with SoapUI and Postman respectively, it works there -- is this possible with Pingdom at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, found the answer myself -- Pingdom can do this without a problem, I only needed to remove line breaks from the SOAP message.

Comment: I'm still facing issues. Should I have a special `HTTP Header` value or encode the `SOAP` message ?